Any quicker method to evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} \left (\frac{1+\sin x \cos \alpha x}{1+\sin x\cos\beta x}\right)^{\cot^3x}$?
Just now, I came across this problem which asks me to evaluate the limit
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left (\frac{1 + \sin(x) \cos(\alpha x)}{1 + \sin(x)\cos(\beta x)}\right) ^ {\cot ^ 3 (x)}$$
However, the standard method (for me) to apply L'Hospital's Rule repeatedly yields a really algebraic-heavy sequence of equations. Although I managed to get the correct answer (verified using Desmos) after nearly half an hour, I reckon there is a better approach.
Could anyone give some ideas or hints?

The answer is $e^{(\beta^2-\alpha^2)/2}$


Are you familiar with Taylor series?

@jjagmath Not really, I've heard of it but I haven't used it to evaluate a limit yet. Could you explain a little?

Basically, you can "approximate" a (sufficiently) differentiable function by a polynomial close to some $x$. For example, if you graph $\sin(x)$ and $x$ you see that around $x=0$ they're pretty similar. Another example is that $\cos(x)$ is very similar to $1-x^2$ around $x=0$ (graph of these here).
So since taking the limit is evaluating the function at $x$'s close to $0$, you can "substitute" the function in the limits for their Taylor polynomial approximations.
@Claude Leibovici's answer uses these approximations for $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Of course, defining what "approximate" and "similar" mean exactly requires more details. Additionally, justifying that substituting the function for the approximation does indeed give the same limit also requires justifying. For a quick overview Wikipedia has some info, and for all the details any Calculus book should cover the details (Spivak's book for example).

@Robert Lee Thanks for the information! I think I get the main idea now.

my expression in the second line looks so big, that it seems out of bounds of the eqn. Please tell me if you don't understand it

I'm following up to @Claude Leibovici's answer, but using a bit different method.
$$\lim_{x→0} \log(A)=\lim_{x→0} \cot ^ 3 (x)\log\left (\frac{1 + \sin(x) \cos(\alpha x)}{1 + \sin(x)\cos(\beta x)}\right)
$$
$$\implies \lim_{x→0} \log(A)= 
\lim_{x→0} \frac{1}{\tan^3 x} \log \bigg( 1+ $$ $\frac{[(1+\sin(x)\cos(\alpha x)-\ (1+\sin(x)\cos(\beta x)]}{1+\sin(x)\cos(\beta x)}\bigg)$
$$= \lim_{x→0} \frac{1}{\tan^3 x} \log \bigg( 1+ \sin(x)\frac{\cos(\alpha x)-\cos(\beta x)}{1+\sin(x)\cos(\beta x)}\bigg)$$
Let $\bigg(\sin(x)\frac{\cos(\alpha x)-\cos(\beta x)}{1+\sin(x)\cos(\beta x)}\bigg)=k,k→0$ for simplicity.
Hence $$\lim_{x→0}\frac{k}{\tan^3x} \frac{\log(1+k)}{k}=\lim_{x→0}\frac{k}{\tan^3x}$$
The denominator of $k$ can be taken as $1$.
Hence we are left with
$$\lim_{x→0} \frac{\sin(x)×2\sin \frac{x(\alpha+\beta)}{2} \sin \frac{x(\beta-\alpha)}{2}}{\tan^3x}$$
This is a Calc 1 level limit problem. Assuming your knowledge about L'Hopital, you will surely be able to solve this. This limit will be equal to $\frac{\beta ^2 - \alpha ^2}{2}$.
Hence $$\lim_{x→0} A=e^\frac{{\beta^2-\alpha^2}}{2}$$

Nice solution! It's really short and quite easy to follow, and the L'Hopital in the end requires only a few lines.

@The_Eureka actually you don't even need L'Hopital, although it'll be bigger by a few lines. Simply divide and multiply by $x,\frac{x(a+b)}{2},\frac{x(b-a)}{2}$ in order to make them in $lim_{u→0} \frac{\sin u}{u}$ form. The numerators automatically counter the $tan^3x$ below as well

Wow, I haven't thought of that before.

Hints
$$A= \left (\frac{1 + \sin(x) \cos(\alpha x)}{1 + \sin(x)\cos(\beta x)}\right) ^ {\cot ^ 3 (x)}$$
$$\log(A)=\cot ^ 3 (x)\log\left (\frac{1 + \sin(x) \cos(\alpha x)}{1 + \sin(x)\cos(\beta x)}\right)$$
Now, use equivalents
$$\sin(x) \sim x \qquad  \cos(kx)\sim 1-k^2x^2  \qquad \cot(x) \sim \frac 1 x$$ Use the long division for the argument of the logarithm.

Following the hints, I arrived at $\log(A) = \frac{1}{x ^ 3} \log \left ( \frac{\alpha ^ 2}{\beta ^ 2} + \frac{(1 - \frac{\alpha ^ 2}{\beta ^ 2})(1 + x)}{1 + x(1 - \beta ^ 2 x ^ 2)}\right ).$ How should I continue, though? It looks like L'Hospital's is inevitable. Is there another trick?

@The_Eureka. Do not isolate anything. Make the long division of  $\frac { 1+x-a^2x^2} {1+x-b^2 x^2 }$ and remember that $\log(1+\epsilon) \sim \epsilon$.

Yeah, I see what you meant. Thanks!
